# Simple Layout Challenge

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a Card that displays the score in a game.  The card will be more complex than this example, but in the middle of the card I want to have a Row.  That Row contains two Columns.  The first Column contains two Rows.  In each of those two Rows is the team name and the score.

```html
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child:  Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Team A'),
                  Text('100'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Team B'),
                  Text('100'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text('15:00'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now I want t wrap the Text widgets that display the team name in a Expanded.  Once I do that I get a long descriptive error that basically says my Row has a parent that does not have a finite width, but it has a child that is asking to expand and these two are in conflict.  I get that they are in conflict.  How do I fix it?  I definitely don't want to give the parent Widget (the Card) a finite width.

Comment: You should take a look to this article, it may help you https://flutter.io/layout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want the scoreboard to look like - this is an instance where a quick mock-up would be a great help.

However, I can tell you why you're getting an exception.

When you wrap your 'Team A' text in an Expanded, during the layout pass flutter gets confused. The top level row has two items, neither of which define any sort of size, so it makes them as large as possible in the cross axis (vertical) and as small as possible in the main axis (horizontal). This means that they delegate their size to their children.

By wrapping 'Team A' in an Expanded, you're basically telling it:

> *"Hey you, your parent widget is pretty big. I want you to take up all of it that isn't already being used instead of being how big you would normally be."*

It responds with

> "Sure boss, but I've just checked and none of my parents actually have
>   a defined size.... so I don't know what to do. Guess I'll just throw an
>   exception."

The fix is to size the parent, which in this case is the column that contains the two rows (geez, that's confusing).

I think from your description what you want is for that column to take up as much space as possible, so you just have to wrap it in expanded as well. So if you do this, your problem should resolve itself:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Text('Team A')),
                    Text('100'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Text('Team B')),
                    Text('100'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('15:00'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

That way, the column containing the two rows expands to take all available space during its layout pass. Once the 'Team A' text gets around to trying its layout pass it can simply size itself (horizontally) to that column.

You can then play around with the flex factor to get everything how you want.

Just an FYI - once you start getting lots of nested containers and rows you might want to consider a [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html). It's slightly more manual as you need to do the layout calculations yourself, but it might be easier in the long run depending on how complex your scoreboard is.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and solution.